# Monitoring the value of radio buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say I have some radio buttons like this

```
<div id="left_col">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="WSDL" id="ws_type_0">
      WSDL</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="NOWSDL" id="ws_type_1">
      Endpoint</label>
  </p>
  <p id="ws_doc">
    <label for="ws_doc">Document:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_doc" id="ws_doc_txt">
  </p>
  <p id="ws_end">
    <label for="ws_end">Endpoint:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_end" id="ws_end_txt">
  </p>
  <p id="ws_ns">
    <label for="ws_ns">Namespace:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_ns" id="ws_ns_txt">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ws_op">Operation:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_op" id="ws_op_txt">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ws_par">Parameter:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_par" id="ws_par_txt">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ws_val">Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_val" id="ws_val_txt">
  </p>
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="Test">
</div>
```

Is there a way to have jQuery monitor continuously for the value of the radio button so that it hides and shows input textboxes accordingly (not just on change but also on page load if I used the checked property inside the html tag)? For now I use the following code to initialize values and hide and show things but I think there's some unnecessary code duplication that can be avoided.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("*").addClass("ui-corner-all ui-widget");
    $("input[type=submit]").button();
    $("#ws_type_0").prop('checked','checked');
    $("#ws_end").hide();
    $("#ws_ns").hide();
    $("input[name=ws_type]").on('change', function() {
        if($(this).val()=="NOWSDL") {
            $("#ws_end").show();
            $("#ws_ns").show();
            $("#ws_doc").hide();
        }
        else if($(this).val()=="WSDL") {
            $("#ws_end").hide();
            $("#ws_ns").hide();
            $("#ws_doc").show();
        }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can DRY up the final `if/else` block by using the `toggle()` method with a state flag. Try this:

```
$("*").addClass("ui-corner-all ui-widget");
$("input[type=submit]").button();
$("#ws_type_0").prop('checked', true);
$("#ws_doc").hide();
$("input[name=ws_type]").on('change', function() {
    var isWSDL = this.value == 'WSDL';
    $("#ws_end, #ws_ns").toggle(isWSDL);
    $("#ws_doc").toggle(!isWSDL);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nvn594a8/1/)

Whether this is better, or more readable, is open to opinion.

Comment: You can dry it up even further with: $("#ws_end,#ws_ns").toggle(isWSDL);

Comment: Thanks, missed that one

Comment: Problem is .on('change', ...) only checks for changes to the value. I thought there was maybe another option in jQuery, so that even refreshing the page while having the second radio button selected would make it trigger? Can't jQuery monitor a value and trigger events when that value equals something specific?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something i made yesterday for an app.  It evaluates if it's a male or not.  I stored the radio values in localstorage first.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("rd"), found = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                    myGender.role = radios[i].value;
                    localStorage.setItem("myGender", JSON.stringify(myGender));
                    location.reload();
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found == 1)
            {
            alert("Please select gender!");
            }
    }
```

then I parse the JSON string to get the value.   then assigned them to variables.

```
var fullInfo, data, genderInfo, gData, gender;
        genderInfo = localStorage.getItem('myGender'); 
        fullInfo = localStorage.getItem("myObject");

        gData = JSON.parse(genderInfo);
        data = JSON.parse(fullInfo);
        var male = "Male";

        gender = gData.role;
        ageInfo = data.age;
        if (gender === male) {
            //do stuff for males here
        } else {
            //do stuff for females here
        }
```